# How persistence works in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I am persisting some dataframes which are stored in var. Now when values to that var changes, how does persistence works? For example:

```
var checkedBefore_c = AddressValidation.validateAddressInAI(inputAddressesDF, addressDimTablePath, target_o, target_c, autoSeqColName).distinct.filter(col(CommonConstants.API_QUALITY_RATING) >= minQualityThreshold)
checkedBefore_c.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)

var pre_checkedBefore_c = checkedBefore_c.except(checkedBefore_o)
pre_checkedBefore_c.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)

checkedBefore_c = pre_checkedBefore_c.drop(target_o).drop(autoSeqColName)
          .withColumn(target_o, pre_checkedBefore_c(target_c))
          .withColumn(CommonConstants.API_STATUS, lit("AI-INSERT"))
          .withColumn(CommonConstants.API_ERROR_MESSAGE, lit(""))

checkedBefore_c = CommonUtils.addAutoIncremetColumn(checkedBefore_c, autoSeqColName)
checkedBefore_c = checkedBefore_c.select(addDimWithLoggingSchema.head, addDimWithLoggingSchema.tail: _*)
checkedBefore_c.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
```

Comment: caching breaks the lineage. The firstcall to `persis` does more harm than benefit. If you don't call `checkedBefore_c` till the end, Spark might still have some optimization that it can make based on the series of transformations that you are making on `checkedBefore_c`.

Comment: So, for one action, If i am writing n number of filters on checked_before_c to produce n new dataframes and later on i am joining all those new dataframes to form one dataframe on which i perform write. No persistence is required. Am i correct here?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to persist checkedBefore_c DataFrame, but in your code you have not called any action.

**Brief  explanation**

Spark has two type of operation, transformation and action.

**Transformation**: Transformations are lazy eventuated like, map, reduceByKey, etc.

**Action**: Actions are eager eventuated, like foreach, count, save etc.

persist and cache are also lazy operation, so till the time you invoke action persist and cache will not be performed.

For more details please refer Action in Spark. You could also refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjuKVv8SiLg&index=5&list=PLfxl5dzojKr4FYnpirDMbTTms2pQ4llg9).

Now how persist work.
In persist, spark store partition in in memory or disk or both. 
Their are various options, for all option refer, org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel source code.

Each executors will be responsible to store their partition, if in memory option is given, first it will try to fit all partition if it does not fit then it will clean old cache data based(It is LRY cache). If still all partition does not fit in memory it will cache partitions which fits in memory and it will leave the rest.

If memory with disk option is selected then, first it will perform all step mentioned above and then left partition will be stored in local disk.

If replication factor is two then, each partition will be cached in two different executors.

In you case you have passed MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER, which means all object will be serialized before caching. By default Java serialization is used, but you could  override it and use Kyro serialization, which is recommended.

Comment: Yes. I have used actions in my code and you are correct about lazy evaluation. But my question here is "I have persisted checkedBefore_c two times because after 1st persistence, i have changed the value of variable with new df". Does that required to persist it second time. If not, will it take the updated dataframe to be persisted everytime we change values

Comment: You need to persist it second time as it won’t automatically      Persist the updated dataframe.

Comment: i think 1st persistence is not required then. Is it required in terms of optimization?

Comment: I dont see any optimization in it. In short RDD/DataFrame, which are being used in two different action or it being used in iterative algorithm are good candidate for caching. Here neither your using it in different action nor you are doing iterative algorithm

Comment: Ok. That will be helpful for me. So, for one action, If i am writing n number of filters on checked_before_c to produce n new dataframes and later on i am joining all those new dataframes to form one dataframe on which i perform write. No persistence is required. Am i correct here?